# How to check listview subitem is empty

Tags: vb.net

In my window application i have list view with 4 column.i want to check 3rd sub item is empty or not in all the rows.if it was empty i need to prompt an error.how to check sub-item 3 doesn't have any values?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
    For Each Itm As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        'The orelse shortcut really works well here, since if the subitem doesn't
        'exist it won't check if the text is empty
        If Itm.SubItems.Count < 4 OrElse Itm.SubItems(3).Text = "" Then
            MsgBox(Itm.Text)
        End If
    Next
```

This checks whether the subitem for the fourth column exists or if it exists it has a value. change the subitem index to choose a different column.

Comment: when the flow reaches the above if condition,it just prompt an error.because there is no value.at the same time it may not be empty

Comment: Sorry forgot to add a condition to check if the fourth subitem exists.  I modified my code to do this.

Comment: when the flow reaches if itm.SubItems(3) condition it prompt the error like the below.It occurs in the case of empty subitem.                                              InvalidArgument=Value of '3' is not valid for 'index'. Parameter name: index

Comment: did you use the Or operator, or the OrElse operator?  The orelse operator is essential.  It tells the program to stop stop the execution of that line if the first condition is true.  I tested that code with lines that had less subitems and lines that had empty subitems and they both work.

Comment: Glad it worked out.  Please remember to mark this thread as answered thanks.